# Why doesn't the method `shouldNotResolve` catch the rejected promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I would expect that `a.shouldNotResolve()` would 'catch' the rejected promise in a.cancelOrder, and return 'expected this to catch', but instead it resolves, returning 'promise resolved anyway'.

```
const a = {

  cancelOrder: function(){
    return Promise.reject('something broke')
    .then((x) => {
      return x;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('this caught the error', e);
    });
  },

  shouldNotResolve: function() {
    return this.cancelOrder()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('promise resolved anyway');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('expected this to catch');
    });
  }
}

a.shouldNotResolve(); // "promise resolved anyway"
```

Why does a.cancelOrder reject, but a.shouldNotResolve resolves anyway?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's already caught ("catched"?) earlier in the chain, as seen in the `cancelOrder` function. If you want to catch it there but still pass the rejection down the chain you need to throw it again:

```
  cancelOrder: function(){
    return Promise.reject('something broke')
    .then((x) => {
      return x;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('this caught the error', e);
      throw e;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you catch this error inside

```
  cancelOrder: function(){
    return Promise.reject('something broke')
    .then((x) => {
      return x;
    })
    .catch((e) => { // <-- this catches all errors
      console.log('this caught the error', e);
    });
  },
```

`catch` is literally like `try-catch` for promises. If you already caught an exception outer one wont catch.

```js
try { 
  try {
    throw new Error('Failed')
  } catch(e) { // first catch
    console.log('inner', e.message)
  }

} catch(e) { // second catch
  console.log('outer', e.message)
}
```

As @robertklep suggests you might want to re-throw

```
  cancelOrder: function(){
    return Promise.reject('something broke')
    .then((x) => {
      return x;
    })
    .catch((e) => { // <-- this catches all errors
      console.log('this caught the error', e);
      return Promise.reject(e) // re-reject
    });
  },
```

```js
const rejected1 = Promise.reject(1)

const resolved = rejected1
  .catch(x => console.log(x))
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))

const rejected2 = rejected1.catch(() => {
  console.log('caught but rethrow')
  return Promise.reject(2)
})

rejected2.catch(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: It'll work properly if the error gets re-thrown inside the `catch` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Write the catch in `cancelOrder` outside the promise flow, so it doesn't put the promise back in success state.

```
const a = {

  cancelOrder: function(){
    const result = Promise.reject('something broke')
      .then((x) => {
        return x;
      });

    result.catch((e) => {
      console.log('this caught the error', e);
    });

    return result;
  },

  shouldNotResolve: function() {
    return this.cancelOrder()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('promise resolved anyway');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('expected this to catch');
    });
  }
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, another option, if you want to put the `catch` in the promise flow, is to re-throw the error.

You might also consider writing an interceptor which does this for you:

```
function doCatch(fn) {
  return function(reason) {
    fn(reason);
    throw reason;
  });
}
```

Now you can write

```
  cancelOrder: function(){
    return Promise.reject('something broke')
      .then((x) => {
        return x;
      })
      .catch(doCatch(err => console.err("this caught the error", e)));
  }
```

By the way, `.then((x) => { return x; })` is a no-op.